# help understanding list of chords in music theory

Tags: theory, chords

from this wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chords

in the main table listing the chords, I am interested in the 5th column (pc pitch class) integer values representing the semitones of the chord. I am writing a piece of software so I want to know integer values from 0 representing the notes of a chord in semitones - not intervals.

in one example, lets use Northern lights chord, it lists the numbers as:

1 2 8 0 3 6 7 t e 4 7.

I assume t is tonic, and is simply the octave - so that would be 11 right?

I am unsure what e represents. my translation of this chord to the data I need for my application looks like this:
1, 2, 8, 0, 3, 6, 7, 11, ?, 15, 18

Can anyone tell me what e represents and if my assumption of t being tonic (octave) is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t = ten
e = eleven

---

In pitch-class notation, the numbers correspond to specific pitches or intervals, modulo 12 (pitches and intervals are all considered without regard to octave. Octave equivalence is assumed).

| Number | Pitch | Interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | C | unison |
| 1 | C#/Db | minor second |
| 2 | D | major second |
| 3 | D#/Eb | minor third |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| 9 | A | major sixth |
| t (10) | A#/Bb | minor seventh |
| e (11) | B | major seventh |

So a C major chord is (0 4 7). However, thinking in terms of intervals, *all* major chords are (0 4 7), where 0 is the root of the chord.

Comment: This reminds me of 'old money' in UK - 12 pennies = 1 shilling, or, still working, 12" = 1' (maybe still working in US?)